# react-hook-form overwrites onChange function and updates value late

Tags: reactjs, typescript, select, onchange, react-hook-form

I made a customized `Select` component with `useState` and `onChange`. And I tried to use it with **react-hook-form**.

Here's the code for `Select` component.

```
const Select = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"input">>((props, ref) => {
  const internalRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [fruit, setFruit] = useState("");
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useImperativeHandle<HTMLInputElement | null, HTMLInputElement | null>(
    ref,
    () => internalRef.current,
    []
  );

  const onClickFruit = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => {
    const fruit = e.currentTarget.textContent as string;
    setFruit(fruit);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFruit(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)}>
        <input 
          id="input"
          type="text"
          ref={internalValue} 
          value={fruit} 
          // problem No.1 comes from below.
          onChange={onChange} 
          {...props} 
        />
      </div>
      {isOpen && (
        <ul>
          <li onClick={onClickFruit}>apple</Li>
          <li onClick={onClickFruit}>peach</Li>
          <li onClick={onClickFruit}>grape</Li>
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And I used this component in the `Form` component with **react-hook-form** as below.

```
interface FormValue {
  fruit: string;
}

const Form = () => {
  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm<FormValue>({ mode: "onChange" });

  const onSubmit = (e: FieldValues) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Select {...register("fruit", {
          validate: (value) => value !== "peach" || "No Peach Allowed!",
        })} 
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Problems are,

1. I can only write text in input when `{...props}` comes before `onChange`. It seems **react-hook-form's onChange** overwrites **input's onChange**. What if I send `onChange` function as prop and want to let both `onChange` functions work?
2. When I select **apple** and change to **peach** then submit the form, it logs **apple** on the console. I expected **peach** to be logged.
3. When I select **peach** or write **peach**, validation isn't triggered though I am using `onChange` mode.
4. error message comes out only after I click the **submit** button.

How can I solve them? Please help.

p.s. I tried `Controller`. I could write but it logged {fruit: undefined} when the form was submitted. Even worse, the input's value wasn't updated when I click the fruits in `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1: To fix this, destructure `props` to `{onChange, ...restProps}` and to `input` component pass only `restProps` so that RHF's `onChange` doesn't override custom `onChange`

Issue 2 & 3 : You need to call destructured `onChange` in both `onChange` and `onClickFruit` functions so that RHF will have updated values. So, these functions can be updated as below

```
const onClickFruit = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => {
    const fruit = e.currentTarget.textContent as string;
    onChange(fruit)
    setFruit(fruit);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const onInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFruit(e.target.value);
    onChange(e.target.value);
  };
```

And update input as below

```
      <input 
          id="input"
          type="text"
          ref={internalValue} 
          value={fruit}
          onChange={onInputChange} 
          {...restProps} 
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to handle the first issue (which may solve the other issues), you need to "merge" the onChange functions.

i.e.

```
  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFruit(e.target.value);
    if (props.onChange) {
        props.onChange(e);
    }
  };
```

Otherwise only one of the two onChange's gets called.

Comment: thx! but it didn't work for me...